# In specifications for switches, what does "250 V / 20(4) A" mean?

Tags: power, amperage

I've specifications of 250V switches here saying "250 V / 20(4) A" or "250 V / 10(4) A". What do these "20(4)" or "10(4)" exactly stand for? Does "250 V / 20(4) A" mean it is a 20 A switch or a 4 A switch?

Comment: Where here? Care to share?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the data sheet of a specific switch?  Could be the AC and DC ratings of a switch.  When used with AC current ratings are often higher as voltage falls to zero several times a second so it cant maintain an arc.

Comment: @Trevor_G If you insist : https://www.reichelt.de/Wippschalter/WIPPE-1555-3102/3/index.html?ACTION=3&LA=446&ARTICLE=154408&GROUPID=7596&artnr=WIPPE+1555.3102 ---- I didn't want to advertise for any shop ...

Comment: @Warren Hill: http://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/C200/WIPPE_1555.3102_DB.pdf --- That's interesting ... The data sheet says something of "20 A" while the technical details are specified with "250 V AC /10 (4) A" on the regular product information page ...

Comment: @Warren Hill: The datasheet http://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/C200/WIPPE_1555.3108_DB.pdf gives two different specifications: One for 10A and one for 16A ... Why two, not one?

Comment: My best guess is peak current (continuous current)

Comment: The [drawing](http://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/C200/WIPPE_1555.3102_DB.pdf) is even weirder... half in Englsh and half in German.

Comment: my guess is 20A resistive load (4A inductive load). With an inductive load, the back EMF can maintain an arc at the contacts for much longer. Unfortunately I don't speak German. Relays are frequently specified for both. 'Geräte Schutzklasse II' seems to be the insulation rating of the switch to chassis, not a specification for the current rating of the contacts.

Comment: I found [this](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/1baaff013e6e31584a7801f9c77d9aae.pdf) too but it does not help.

Comment: Though [This](https://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Marquardt-Switches/15553102/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtFyPk3yBMYYPEigRpNlkoHFFK7ts9ptk4%3D) might.

Comment: Thanks a lot, all of you. I would like to use this as a power switch for quite some electronic devices connected to it. The switch should work for 1000 to 2000W just to be on the safe side. Best approach would be to use a "250 V AC/20(4) A" switch, I guess?